# Pandas: Mapping overlap between columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6], 'col2': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c',  'd', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'e']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like to see how `col1` maps up to `col2` and vice-versa.

I can get groupby counts to see how many elements map to each element for both columns

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)

col1
3    2
2    2
1    2
6    1
5    1
4    1

df.groupby('col2')['col1'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)

col2
e    3
b    2
a    2
d    1
c    1
```

Is there a good way to see which elements of `col1` overlap with elements of `col2`?

For example in `col1`, both `1` and `2` map to `b` in `col2`.

The output could either be a count of the number of overlaps for each element in `col1`, or a list of the elements that it overlaps with

Result:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'col2': [[2, 3], [1], [1, 2, 6], [],  [], [1,2] ]}
overlap = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `groupby` with `agg`

```
df.groupby('col2').col1.agg(list)
Out[21]: 
col2
a       [1, 3]
b       [2, 1]
c          [4]
d          [5]
e    [2, 3, 6]
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code in your Jupyter notebook; I think this is what you were looking to get as an output. It provides the col1 count for each unique value from col2.

```
for element in df.col2.unique():
    print(element, '\n',  df.where(df.col2 == element).col1.value_counts())
```

Where the output is element from col1/ count of letter:

```
a 
3    1
1    1
 Name: col1, dtype: int64
b 
 1    1
 2    1
 Name: col1, dtype: int64
c 
 4    1
 Name: col1, dtype: int64
d 
 5    1
 Name: col1, dtype: int64
e 
 6    1
 3    1
 2    1
 Name: col1, dtype: int64
```